# How to use selectall-hashref for all columns

Tags: perl

I would like to implement this subroutine using `selectall_hashref`:

```
sub query {
    use SQL::Abstract;
    my $sql = SQL::Abstract->new;
    my ($table, $fields, $where) = @_;
    my ($stmt, @bind) = $sql->select($table, $fields, $where);
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare($stmt);
    $sth->execute(@bind);
    my @rows;
    while(my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array() ) {
        my %data;
        @data{ @{$sth->{NAME}} } = @row;
        push @rows, \%data;
    }
    return \@rows;
}
```

Unfortunately `selectall_hashref` requires a list of wanted columns. Is there a way to write something similar my first subroutine?

Obviously this doesn't work:

```
sub query {
   return $dbh->selectall_hashref(shift, q/*/);
}
```

The expected output could be an array of hashes or an hash of hashes:

```
{ '1' => { column1 => 'foo', column2 => 'bar' }, 
  '2' => { column1 => '...', column2 => '...' },
  ... }
```

or

```
[ { column1 => 'foo', column2 => 'bar' }, 
  { column1 => '...', column2 => '...' },
  ... ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is `selectall_arrayref`, not `selectall_hashref`. That does this exactly.

```
use DBI;
use Data::Printer;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:database=foo;', 'foo', 'bar');

my $foo = $dbh->selectall_arrayref(
  'select * from foo',
  { Slice => {} }
);

p $foo

__END__

\ [
    [0]   {
        id    1,
        baz   "",
    },
    [1]   {
        id    2,
        baz   "",

    },
]
```